# What algorithm is used for audio feature extraction in google's audioset?

Tags: audio, machine-learning, sound-recognition

I am getting started with Google's [Audioset](https://research.google.com/audioset/download.html).  While the dataset is extensive, I find the information with regards to the audio feature extraction very vague.  The website mentions

> 128-dimensional audio features extracted at 1Hz. The audio features were extracted using a VGG-inspired acoustic model described in Hershey et. al., trained on a preliminary version of YouTube-8M. The features were PCA-ed and quantized to be compatible with the audio features provided with YouTube-8M. They are stored as TensorFlow Record files.

Within the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.09430.pdf), the authors discuss using mel spectrograms on 960 ms chunks to get a 96x64 representation.  It is then unclear to me how they get to the 1x128 format representation used in the Audioset.  Does anyone know more about this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use the `96*64` data as input for a modified `VGG` network.The last layer of `VGG` is `FC-128`, so its output will be `1*128`, and that is the reason.

The architecture of `VGG` can be found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/audioset/vggish_slim.py